# package javax.mail and javax.mail.internet do not exist

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

When I compile a simple code that has the following 2 import statements:

`import javax.mail.*`

`import javax.mail.internet.*`

I get the following message:

`package javax.mail does not exist`

`package javax.mail.internet does not exist`

Why do I get this error?

Here is the code I have:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

class tester {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.com" , "smtp.gmail.com");
   Session session  = Session.getDefaultInstance( props , null);
   String to = "me@gmail.com";
   String from = "from@gmail.com";
   String subject = "Testing...";
   Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
      msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO , new InternetAddress(to));
      msg.setSubject(subject);
      msg.setText("Working fine..!");
    }  catch(Exception exc) {
       }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to download the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), and put the relevant jar files in your classpath.

Answer (score 17):

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) `javax.mail.jar` and add it to your project using the following steps:

1. Extract the mail.jar file
2. Right click the project node (JavaMail), click Properties to change properties of the project
3. Now go to Libraries Tab
4. Click on Add JAR/Folder Button. A window opens up.
5. Browse to the location where you have unzipped your Mail.jar
6. Press ok
7. Compile your program to check whether the JAR files have been successfully included

Comment: Your link on where to get it is now old. Also, it's not called mail.jar, either, but, I believe, javax.mail.jar. . . And if it IS supposed to be called mail.jar, that might in fact be why I even stumbled across this older question!

Answer (score 16):

If using maven, just add to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course, you need to check the [current version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.5.0-b01).

Answer (score 13):

You need the `javax.mail.jar` library.
Download it from the [Java EE JavaMail GitHub page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) and add it to your IntelliJ project:

1. Download `javax.mail.jar`
2. Navigate to `File > Project Structure...`
3. Go to the Libraries tab
4. Click on the `+` button (Add New Project Library)
5. Browse to the `javax.mail.jar` file
6. Click OK to apply the changes

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still looking to use the aforementioned IMAP library but need to use gradle, simply add this line to your modules gradle file (not the main gradle file)

```
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.1'
```

The links to download the .jar file were dead for me, so had to go with an alternate route.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you do not have the necessary .jar files that give you access to the Java Mail API. These can be downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need the javax.mail.jar library. Download it from the https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javamail-releases.html and add it to your Eclipse project:

If you are using <module-info.java> then,

1. Right-click on Project, go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> ModulePath -> Add External Jars.
2. Browse to the javax.mail.jar file
3. Click "Apply and Close".

Under module-info.java, add this:

```
module TestApp {
    **requires mail;**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the classpath of your `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` file like that:

open the command prompt:

```
c:\user>set classpath=%classpath%;d:\jarfiles\mail.jar;d:\jarfiles\activation.jar;.;
```

and if u don't have the both file then please download them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) the Java mail jars.
2. Extract the downloaded file.
3. Copy the ".jar" file and paste it into `ProjectName\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder
4. Right click on the Project and go to Properties
5. Select Java Build Path and then select Libraries
6. Add JARs...
7. Select the .jar file from `ProjectName\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` and click OK

   that's all

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Obviously these .jars were included with Java <= v8.x out of the box, but are not anymore. Thus one has to separately download them and place them in the appropriate classpath as highlighted by several folks above. I understand that the new Java is modularized and thus potentially more light-weight (which is certainly a good thing, since the old setup was a monster). On the other hand this - as we can see - breaks lots of old build setups. Since the time to fix these isn't chargeable to Oracle I guess this made their decision easy...

Answer (score 0):

you need mail.jar and activation.jar to build javamail application

Comment: I haven't found activation.jar in the javamail api.But my program is error free now ! ??

Comment: @grassPro, and future referrers: "Note: Unless you're using Java SE 6 or newer, you will also need the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) extension that provides the javax.activation package." This note is from Oracle's site

Comment: @Viren ...Is this "activation package" still needed? The project is now an open source one, independent of Oracle and I didn't see mention of it in the materials, but then, my first project trying to use it isn't yet working!

Answer (score 0):

Download "javamail1_4_5.zip" file from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.5-oth-JPR

Extract zip file and put the relevant jar file ("mail.jar") in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this for myself, so hope this helps. My project runs on **GlassFish 4**, **Eclipse MARS**, with **JDK 1.8** and **JavaEE 7**.

Firstly, you can find `javax.mail.jar` in the extracted `glassfish` folder: `glassfish4->glassfish->modules`

Next, in **Eclipse**, Right Click on your project in the explorer and navigate the following: `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARs->` Go to the aforementioned folder to add `javax.mail.jar`