# Java Mail can't find the class MimeMessage

Tags: java, session, jakarta-mail, mime-message

This is the code of the class Mail (there are a main inside but for the simple reason that in this way it seem to be simple to solve this problem):

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Mail {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "mail";
    String psw = "password";

    // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
    String host = "localhost";

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.user", from);
    properties.setProperty("mail.password", psw);

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new                        InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("This is actual message");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the terminal i see after the running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at Mail.main(Mail.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error is on :

> MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

Comment: What version of java are you using ?
Did you put Java Mail API jar in your classpath ? Here is how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606529/package-javax-mail-and-javax-mail-internet-do-not-exist

Comment: @neimar Yes i put all the API required, searching on the internet i found that there are some problem with Java 9, but idk how i can fix it..

Answer (score 2):

You either need to tell JDK 9 to expose the included-but-hidden java.activation module, or you need to include the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF; javax.activation) jar file in your project explicitly.

Do the former by adding `--add-modules java.activation` to your `java` command line.

The latter can be done by using this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MailTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = "tomail";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "frommail";
    String psw = "password";

    // different mail will have different host name, I have implemented using gmail
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String port = "587";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
   // props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", timeout);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    // Get the default Session object.
    //Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
    {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
      {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, psw);
      }
    });

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("This is actual message");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of java mail api you are using?

Comment: The error will  occur if the jar is not added properly in the classpath. What environment setup you are using? such as build tool, IDE etc

Comment: I use JavaMail 1.4.7 and Java EE 6

Comment: Any build tool or IDE?

Comment: I use intellij Idea @AfrockiaRaj

Comment: Add external JavaMail 1.4.7 jar correctly using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: oh what was a problem?

Comment: IDK the problem is on the line "MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)", they can't find the class

Comment: Yaa fine, I'm asking about the fix you made?

Comment: I haven't fixed nuffing yet, the problem is still the same.